# save pdf on ipad memory and not in my documents directory

Tags: pdf, xcode4.3, save, ios5.1

I created a pdf file in ios using objective-C and is able to save it in my applications Document directory. 
I wanted to know if it is possible to save the generated pdf in the ipad memory, so that i do not need my application to show the generated pdf. In other words I do not want to store it in the documents directory but somewhere on the ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be fully understanding what you are asking but; You can transfer PDF's directly to the iPad via regular cable syncing/itunes so it can be viewed in iBooks on the ipad. Just drag the PDF into itunes, it goes to books section and you can sync it.

Comment: I have my own application in which i generate the pdf programmatically. I am able to save it in the documents directory of my application. I wanted to know that instead of saving in my documents directory, can i save it on the ipads memory so that i do not need my application to see the generate pdf.

Comment: O okay, i cant say exactly how or if you can do that but i found this maybe relevant section in the apple developer library: 

Writes the document data to disk at the sandbox location indicated by a file URL.

The full article is at : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDocument 

Pretty comprehensive article it seems, hopefully you find something in there than can help.